# Kubuntu 14.04 download source

Tags: linux, iso, download, kubuntu

I want to download and use Kubuntu `14.04` (a.k.a Trusty Tahr ) ISO ( for testing some features on the latest KDE 4 release ) but looks like the [official download link](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04.5/release/kubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso) is no longer available. In the [Old releases page](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/) also there are releases ranging from `5.04` to `11.10` at the time of writing , but not `14.04` or `14.10`

So does anybody know where can I find a mirror for downloading it ?

Everything I've found so far via googling is a link to the [official one](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04.5/release/kubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso) which is not available anymore .

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to download it via [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/2018*/http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04.5/release/kubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso). There were two copies of it available between 2016 and 2018.